# OSX Application: how to make window maximized?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I am working on a mac application, and I like to make initial window be in maximized state, like when you are pressing green button with plus sign.
I don't want it to be full screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "zoom" a window to the max available space by using NSScreen's `visibleFrame` as the target frame. Let's say `window` is your NSWindow IBOutlet:

```
if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
    window.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true, animate: true)
}
```

For example, in the AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
            window.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true, animate: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new in mac world. I just put this code in NSViewController:viewDidLoad and its not working can you tel me where to put this code exactly. this is my code if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
            self.view.window?.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true, animate: true)
        }

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Update for Swift 3: just replace `.mainScreen()` with `.main()`.

Comment: this code works and windows is fullscreened. But after click on esc, application crash. What is the reason ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be on main screen, but you may use `window.screen`

Answer (score 11):

An app in its zoomed state is not the same thing as "maximized." The green plus icon indicates zoom, which means "the appropriate size for this content." In some applications that's the visible frame (as Eric D. discusses), but it can be almost anything. Try zooming a Safari window for instance.

Assuming you really want "maximized" and not "zoom", then Eric is on the right track, but it can be done better. First, you should use the window's screen if it has one. Also, you should not animate the window resize during launch (since that can look awkward on launch).

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    if let screen = window.screen ?? NSScreen.mainScreen() {
        window.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true)
    }
}
```

You may want to consider using a `NSWindowController` to manage this rather than putting it in the application delegate. In that case, you can put this in `windowDidLoad`. Window controllers are a pretty common tool in AppKit (as opposed to view controllers, which are not historically as common).

If you actually want zoom behavior, familiarize yourself with the the `NSWindowDelegate` method `windowWillUseStandardFrame(_:defaultFrame:)`. You shouldn't generally call `zoom(_:)` directly on launch because that will animate, but whatever logic you do in the delegate should be used to compute your frame. Again, make sure to adjust your frame to live on the window's screen if it has one, rather than the main screen.

Ideally, you really should be honoring the last frame that the user used rather than forcing it to the visible frame. That's called `frameAutosave` in Cocoa if you want to research that more. A window controller will help you manage that somewhat automatically if you just set a autosave name in Interface Builder. (Though it's slightly complicated by needing to compute the frame on first launch to get the visible frame, so it won't be completely automatic.)

Do give some careful thought before making your default frame be the visible frame in any case. That can be really enormous on large monitors (there are still a lot of 30" Cinema displays out there, but even on a 27" it can be pretty overwhelming). Sometimes that's fine depending on your app, but I often find that it's worth defining a maximum initial size (while allowing the user to make it larger).

Comment: Rob - good one.

Answer (score 4):

in Swift 4.2:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
 override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    view.window?.zoom(self) //bespread the screen

  //view.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)  //fullscreen
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**2020 | SWIFT 5.1:**

use extension:

```
extension NSWindowController {
    func maximize() { self.window?.zoom(self) }
}
```

just call `maximize()` of NSWindowController instance :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

If anyone's still having issues, trying calling the zoom function the main thread. Worked for me.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
     self.view.window?.zoom(self)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I really appreciate your help.

I am working on a document based mac application. I put the code you provided in the makeWindowControllers() of Document class and it works like a charm.

Thank you very much. Here is the code I use.

```
override func makeWindowControllers() {
        // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let windowController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("Document Window Controller") as! NSWindowController
        self.addWindowController(windowController)

        if let screen = NSScreen.mainScreen() {
            windowController.window?.setFrame(screen.visibleFrame, display: true, animate: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works well only on single-windowed application, but it's really easy to edit to work with multy-windowed application

usage to maximize and unmaximize window:

```
TheApp.maximized.toggle()
```

Source code

```
public class TheApp {
    static var maximized: Bool {
        get {
            guard let visibleFrame = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame,
                  let window = NSApp.mainWindow
            else { return false }
            
            return window.frame == visibleFrame
        }
        set { NSApp.mainWindow?.zoom(newValue) }
    }
    
    static var fullscreen: Bool {
        get {
            guard let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.frame,
                  let window = NSApp.mainWindow
            else { return false }
            
            return window.frame == screenFrame
        } set {
            NSApp.mainWindow?.toggleFullScreen(newValue)
        }
    }
    
    static var mimimized: Bool {
        get { NSApp.mainWindow?.isMiniaturized ?? false }
        set { NSApp?.mainWindow?.miniaturize(newValue) }
    }
}
```