# How do I create an IBOutlet for NSWindow Xcode macOS

Tags: swift, macos, xcode9.2

I am trying to create an IBOutlet for NSWindow in AppDelegate.swift, I am able to create IBOutlets for buttons by control + dragging from storyboard to swift file, but I am not able to do this for NSWindow. How do I do this?
Xcode 9.2 Swift 4.0

Thanks

Comment: You can create an outlet for the controls available in the view library only.  Create a property if you want to reference the window in AppDelegate.

Comment: I tried using @property but it gives an error: ```unknown attribute 'property'```

Comment: I'm trying to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314789/osx-application-how-to-make-window-maximized

Comment: `@property` is an ObjC keyword. You should be looking up how to use an @IBOutlet in Swift

Comment: Where is `@property` in that url link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a window property:

```
weak var window: NSWindow?
```

Main window reference:

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
    }
```

Comment: @Dregg What you need is to use the view controller's view window property. Just make sure to access it on viewWillAppear or any other method other than viewDidLoad which window will always be nil https://stackoverflow.com/a/43426545/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, that worked as well

Comment: @Dregg Make sure to use the view window. It will always return the correct window. It is not necessarily always the first window.